# wav playback in Matlab while recording speech

Tags: matlab, audio, wav, recording

I am facing problem while recording speech for 5 seconds. I have sucessfully played back using play() function , but once i play the wav file i have saved on my desktop,it is nothing but silence. 
This is the code

```
clc,clear;
% Record your voice for 5 seconds.
%recObj = audiorecorder;
recObj = audiorecorder(96000, 16, 1);
disp('Start speaking.')
recordblocking(recObj,5);

disp('End of Recording.');`enter code here`
% Play back the recording.
play(recObj);
myspeech = getaudiodata(recObj,'double');
wavwrite(double(myspeech),'C://Users//naveen//Desktop//unprocessed')

% Store data in double-precision array.
myRecording = getaudiodata(recObj);

% Plot the samples.
figure,plot(myRecording),title('Original Sound');
```

Comment: I think the default sample rate for wavwrite is 8000Hz, your recording is set to 96000Hz, try `wavwrite(double(myspeech),96000,'C:/...snip...` **or** `recObj = audiorecorder(8000, 16, 1)`;

Comment: Thanks a ton.. i tried wavwrite(double(myspeech),96000,'C:/...snip...   and it worked. Now i can hear the recorded voice distinctly. Thankyou

Comment: ok ill add is as an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`wavwrite` is called with out a sample rate specified and the default is 8000Hz

however the recording is set to 96000Hz in your call to `audiorecorder`

```
audiorecorder(96000, 16, 1);
```

Changeing these two to match should fix the issue so change either of the calls to one of the following

```
recObj = audiorecorder(8000, 16, 1)
wavwrite(double(myspeech),96000,'C:/...snip...
```

As an added note I think `myspeech` is already double (as specified in `getaudiodata`)
so `wavwrite(myspeech,96000,'C:/...snip...` should work just as well!